# Insertar Varios registros en Campo Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, tengo una tabla llamada solicitud para ingreso de nuevos requerimientos. En esta solicitud el usuario tendrá la opción de seleccionar varios servicios mediante combobox y agregarlos a la solicitud. Hasta ahora he logrado guardar en la tabla cuando solo tengo un servicio, pero lo que necesito y por ahora desconozco como manejar es que se seleccionen varios servicios y almacenar toda esa información en el mismo campo de mi tabla.

La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

***TABLA SOLICITUD***
ID (INT 50, AUTO_INCREMENT),
NOMBRE USUARIO (VARCHAR 50),
ID_SERVICIO (INT 50), LLAVE FORANEA A TABLA SERVICIO
ESTADO (INT 10)

***TABLA SERVICIO***
ID (INT 50, AUTO_INCREMENT),
NOMBRE SERVICIO (VARCHAR 50),
ESTADO (INT 10)

Espero que por favor alguien me pueda orientar a resolver este problema.

EJEMPLO DE UN INSERT EN LA TABLA SOLICITUD:

INSERT INTO SOLICITUD (nombre_usuario, id_servicio, estatus) VALUES ('JUAN PEREZ','1','REGISTRADO')

EJEMPLO DE COMO DEBERIA GUARDAR LOS SERVICIOS EN LA TABLA SOLICITUD:

INSERT INTO SOLICITUD (nombre_usuario, id_servicio, estatus) VALUES ('JUAN PEREZ','1,2,3,4,5','REGISTRADO')

Comment: Hola puedes ser un poco mas especifico con tu problema? puedes añadir imagenes y coloca el codigo php, el metodo de envio debe estar tomadno solo una variable, de paso lo que estas pidiendo no es posible realizarlo ya que tienes 3 campos pero quieres agregar 8 valores cuando solo puedes agregar 3 (segun lo que estas explicando)

Comment: Si lo notas no hay 8 valores como dices, '1,2,3,4,5' es uno solo

Comment: @ndrs eso se puede separar con "," ?? que yo sepa no puedes colocar eso, porque si despues quieres buscarlo 1 a 1 no podra

Comment: @CriticalGhost pues si es un campo varchar sí, solamente se le da ese formato en el método que use para hacer el insert y listo, obviamente si es un campo de enteros no se puede

Comment: @ndrs pero si miras bien la pregunta en la tabla solicitud si dice que es int, no puede llamar mas de 1

Comment: @CriticalGhost tienes razón amigo, no lo había visto bien es que estoy desde el celular, está mal y no se puede hacer, tiene que cambiar el tipo del campo

Comment: Entonces ID_SERVICIO deberia ser VARCHAR???

Comment: Y es posible que la llave foránea sea VARCHAR???

Comment: No puedes poner varios ID dentro de un campo que es clave foránea. Por la estructura de las tablas, debes insertar una fila por cada solicitud de servicio.

Comment: Y de que manera modificando mis tablas podría lograr que se almacenen varios registros en un solo campo???

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo no puedes agregar mas de 8 datos que tiene tu tabla SOLICITUD, segundo si conviertes el campo de la llave foranea a varchar tampoco va a funcionar porque asi sea un varchar va a tener asociado solo un servicio, ud quiere tener asociados varios servicios en la llave foranea ID_SERVICIO pero como explico esta haciendo una relación que no se si sea (OneToOne o ManyToOne).
Lo que puede hacer es tomar los servicios seleccionados, recorrerlos con un ciclo for e ir anexando uno por uno ej:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $select.Length(); $i++) {
    INSERT INTO SOLICITUD (nombre_usuario, id_servicio, estatus) VALUES 
    ('JUAN PEREZ',$select[$i],'REGISTRADO')
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero tengo una duda, como quedaría almacenada y concatenada la información de $select????